# How to prevent entity to be null

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following question, so I have ER-Diagram and `PREIS` and `GUELTIG_BIS` can be **NULL**. Do I add NULL at the end e.g. `GUELTIG_BIS DATE NULL, PREIS DECIMAL(8,2) NULL` or without NULL `GUELTIG_BIS DATE, PREIS DECIMAL(8,2)`

[image]

Comment: Do you want it to be nullable or do you want to prevent it to be null? Your title and question don't match.

Comment: @I want to prevent it to be nullable

Comment: `NULL` is default, you don't need to specify it to allow null values.

Answer (score 0):

When a you don't want a column to have null values, you add NOT NULL at it. If you want a column to hold null values, you don't have to add NULL because a column can hold null values by default. You can visit this site to see an exemple : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_notnull.asp